# Error while sending message to SSL enabled Kafka Broker

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

We have set up a kafka instance and enabled encryption.

While trying to connect to Kafka broker using console consumer/producer we get the below error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 2
```

We have validated that the setup is correct, can see that kafka broker is up and listening. The certificates are valid.

We have tried enabling -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake on the Kafka vm configuration. Doesn't seem to help much
Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Is the producer and consumer also setup with keystores? You have to set SSL settings on clients too.